# Is there a way to put kids up for adoption in Virtual Families 2?

Tags: virtual-families-2

This may sound mean ( because it is ), but I want to put one of my kids for adoption.

REASONS: I can't tell if it's a boy or girl. It's name is Benghi. I just naturally hate it. :(

I know its mean but I just want to know: Can you put infants/kids up for adoption?

That way he/she still gets a family :)

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Isn't there another way to get rid of it? Looks like meat's back on the menu boys

Comment: So tempted to edit this so its title lacks context.

Comment: @Rapitor Doooo eeeeet.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. If you hate the child, you can send it to boarding school and never see it again. Just make sure they have lots of other kids so you can choose a different one to inherit the house.

By the way, Benghi is a boys name in Virtual Families.

Comment: > If you hate the child, you can send it to boarding school -

Ah, just like real life. ;)

Answer (score -2):

No, but you can send them to boarding school.

Comment: As you can see, someone else provided the same information months ago. This answer adds nothing new.